# openpyxl Warning (from warnings module) python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Actualmente tengo un archivo de excel con dos hojas, en la primera (TD) tengo varias formulas que se encargan de hacer algunos cálculos con los datos de la hoja 2(Base GRAL), la segunda hoja la alimento con  el resultado de una consulta SQL, para esto estoy usando openpyxl, el cual hace el ejercicio de poblar la hoja 2(Base GRAL), pero al terminar me esta ocacionando dos situaciones, la primera me daña todas las formulas de la primer hoja, por ejemplo tengo esta formula
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO('Base GRAL'!$F:$F;"VENDIDA";'Base GRAL'!$I:$I;TD!$B5)
,que despúes de ejecutarse me daña la referencia quedando de este modo:
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO('Base GRAL'!#¡REF!;"VENDIDA";'Base GRAL'!#¡REF!;TD!$B5).

y lo segundo me arroja este error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.0.10-py3.10.egg\openpyxl\comments\shape_writer.py", line 74
FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions. Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
```

Este es mi código:

```
def export():
    dataExport = []
    base = Base_excel(dataExport)  
    
    EjecutarMacro(ruta = "/Estructura_Inf.xlsm",archivo = "Estructura_Inf",modulo = "Módulo1",macro = "Limpiar",seg = 10)

    l_Estructura = openpyxl.load_workbook("/Estructura_Inf.xlsm",read_only = False, keep_vba = True)
    h_Estructura = l_Estructura.worksheets[1]

    print(h_Estructura)

x = 0
for row in base:
    if x >0:
        h_Estructura.append(row)
    x = x + 1
    

l_Estructura.save("/Estructura_Inf.xlsm")
l_Estructura.close()
```

Comment: Ese problema posiblemente radique en tu macro Limpiar. Sin verla es posible que la macro borre el contenido de la hoja (o elimine la hoja) y por ende las fórmulas, al no encontrar ya contenido, fallan al intentar referenciarlas desde otra hoja. 
Sin probarlo se me ocurre que primero desactives el cálculo automático y una vez hayas terminado el proceso vuelvas a activarlo. 
Otra opción es, mediante código, volver a escribir las fórmulas en tu primera hoja una vez hayas poblado la hoja2.
El segundo error te está avisando de que estás utilizando un método que en futuras versiones va a cambiar.

Comment: @dogwall muchas gracias por tu observación, efectivamente en la ejecución de la macro estaba el lio, ya que limpiaba la hoja eliminando columnas, al hacer esto eliminaba la referencia de las formulas.
Respecto la observación de cambios en futuras versiones, me queda la duda a fuerza debo de actualizar el código que ya he hecho en proyectos?